# Give me some tips to resolve this problem

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to create an anonymous block which will calculate the number of rows in the table with the name and selection criterion determined at runtime.

This is my attempt:

```
DECLARE
    tableName VARCHAR2(45) :=:numeTable;
    col VARCHAR2(45):=:campul;
    val VARCHAR2(30):=:idValue;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    'select count(*) from :tableName where :col = :val'
    USING tableName, col, val;
END;
```

Comment: Please tag your database.

Answer (score 0):

You can't *bind* table or column names; concatenate them (and beware of SQL injection).

```
SQL> declare
  2    tablename varchar2(30) := 'emp';
  3    col       varchar2(30) := 'job';
  4    val       varchar2(30) := 'CLERK';
  5    l_cnt     number;
  6  begin
  7    execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' || dbms_assert.sql_object_name(tableName) ||
  8                      '  where ' || dbms_assert.simple_sql_name(col) || ' = :a'
  9      into l_cnt
 10      using val;
 11
 12    dbms_output.put_line('count = ' || l_cnt);
 13  end;
 14  /
count = 4

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```